# i need to send through the GET method data using the thickbox library and jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, methods, thickbox

cause i got some 403 errors ... that's beacuse my server doesn't has enabled the directory listing
anybody has done something like that ?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
/* 'somepage.php' is our script source.
   'username'     is our varible, jonathansampson is the value
   'result'       will hold anything the script sends back
   'text'         is the type of data we're expecting. */
$.get("somepage.php", {"username":"jonathansampson"}, function(result){

  alert(result);

}, "text");
```